# How do I download all my blogger posts?

Tags: blogger

Is there any way I can download all my posts from blogger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this tool called [Blogger Backup](http://www.codeplex.com/bloggerbackup/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=6978). Its free and open-source.

Answer (score 4):

**How to save entire blog as PDF**

If you want to save your entire blog as an awesome PDF file which people can read and enjoy instead of having a dull .xml file, use [Blogbooker](http://blogbooker.com/) or follow these steps:

Step 1: Blogger dashbord>Settings>Posts and comments>Posts> Show at most
Put show at most 999999 posts on the main page. (Any large number)

Step 2: View your blog website. Print it (Ctrl+P) and choose the destination as "Save as PDF". Click on 'Older posts' and repeat. (If you have a lot of posts you'd have multiple pages so you'd have to click older posts) You should have multiple PDF files.

Step 3: Go to [PDF combine](http://www.pdfcombine.com/) and combine your PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is to take your blog with you, exporting it is the option; unless what you're looking for is to export *only* your posts.

To export your entire blog:

`Exporting` > From your blogger dashboard > `Settings` > Under `BASIC` Tab > The first block is `Blog Tools` > `Export`.

Save the file and then upload it where you need to.

Comment: The export option is no longer available.